# WEKA CVParameterSelection for nominal options (such as NaiveBayes -K or -D)

Tags: machine-learning, weka

This may be impossible, and even not sensible but I was wondering if it was possible in WEKA to do this.

I have my NaiveBayes classifier, and I want it to decide through cross folds which option is best to use, -D for discrete or -K for kernel based.

```
ParamSelection ps = new ParamSelection();
ps.setClassifier(new NaiveBayes());
ps.setCVParameters("K D");
```

With a decision tree we do it like this, but the -K and -D options don't require numeric parameters.

```
ParamSelection ps = new ParamSelection();
ps.setClassifier(new J48());
ps.setCVParameters("M 3 5 2");
```

Comment: couldn't you just get the cross-validation scores for each of the options and compare them manually?

Comment: I was looking for a way of doing it automatically, but I think I will do that yes